# Count consecutive rows with same value for a column in a database using django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

My App consists of a notification module. If the notifications are consecutively arrived from a same user, I would like to show "n notifications from john doe".

eg:

The database rows are as:

```
id    |   user    |     notif       |
------------------------------------
1       john doe     liked your pic 
2       john doe     commented on your pic
3       james        liked your pic
4       james        commented on your pic
5       john doe     pinged you
6       john doe     showed interest
7       john doe     is busy
```

The above notifications are to be shown as:

```
2 notifications from john doe
2 notification from james
3 notofications from john doe
```

How would I count these consecutive rows with same value in a column using django orm?

```
Notification.objects.all().values('user', 'notif_count').group_consecutive_by('user').as(notif_count=Sum())
```

Something like that. Please help.

Comment: If I understood your question right you want to implement some kind of notification history but with ordering by date and grouped by user?

Comment: I am not sure, but I don't think you can do that with Aggregation. What you can do is that `5 notifications from John Doe, 2 Notification from James`.

Comment: @SergeyPugach yup! it is.

Comment: @ruddra It's possible(not with Aggregation solely) I have just found the solution. Will write it soon. Thanks.

Comment: @Shameless I am very interested in your solution, could you please post it here?

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov Check the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let my model `Notification` model be:

```
Class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='notifications',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    notif = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The database rows are as:

```
id    |   user    |     notif       |
------------------------------------
1       john doe     liked your pic 
2       john doe     commented on your pic
3       james        liked your pic
4       james        commented on your pic
5       john doe     pinged you
6       john doe     showed interest
7       john doe     is busy
```

Basically, I am trying to join consecutive rows by `user`

The above notifications then are to be shown as:

```
2 notifications from john doe
2 notification from james
3 notofications from john doe
```

instead of

```
5 notifications from john doe
2 notification from james
```

or

```
1 notifications from john doe
1 notifications from john doe
1 notification from james
1 notification from james
1 notofications from john doe
1 notofications from john doe
1 notofications from john doe
```

In  order to achieve this, we are looking for a dictionary like:

```
{
"john doe": ["notif1", "notif2"],
"james": ["notif1", "notif2"],
"john doe": ["notif1", "notif2", "notif3"] #duplicate key.
}
```

But, that's not possible as duplicate keys are not allowed. Hence I am going with array of tuples instead.

```
[
  ('john doe', ['notif1', 'notif2']),
  ('james', ['notif1', 'notif2']),
  ('john doe', ['notif1', 'notif2', 'notif3']),
]
```

So, we first sort the `Notifications` by `date_created`. Then we use `itertools.groupby` to make groups per user.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

qs = Notification.objects.select_related('user').order_by('date_created')
notifs= [(u, list(nf)) for (u, nf) in groupby(qs, attrgetter('user'))]
```

You have everything sorted as needed in `notifs`.

Done!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew about groupby but hoped you've found the solution in SQL, which would be useful for further filtering/ordering.